# How to load images from documents directory into image view in Objective-C

Tags: ios, objective-c

```
NSString *path = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@",[NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory,NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0], parentFolderName] ;
NSArray *dirContents = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] contentsOfDirectoryAtPath:path error:nil];
NSEnumerator *enumerator = [dirContents objectEnumerator] ;
id fileName ;
NSMutableArray *fileArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init] ;
while (fileName = [enumerator nextObject])
{
    NSString *fullFilePath = [path stringByAppendingPathComponent:fileName];
    NSRange textRangeJpg = [[fileName lowercaseString] rangeOfString:[@".png" lowercaseString]];

    if (textRangeJpg.location != NSNotFound)
    {
        originalImage = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:fullFilePath];
        [fileArray addObject:originalImage];
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the issue you are facing? Please provide more details of what is the issue you are facing?

Comment: image not displaying on image view i am getting image array list i want show show image?

Comment: do you get any error? Did you put a break point and check the `fullFilePath`? What are you doing with `fileArray`? That's just an array, post the code of how you actually add the image on to the screen.

Comment: while (fileName = [enumerator nextObject])
    {
        NSString *fullFilePath = [path stringByAppendingPathComponent:fileName];
        NSRange textRangeJpg = [[fileName lowercaseString] rangeOfString:[@".png" lowercaseString]];     
        if (textRangeJpg.location != NSNotFound)
        {
           originalImage = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:fullFilePath];
           // [fileArray addObject:originalImage];
            _drawingView.backgroundColor=[UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[fileArray objectAtIndex:0]];
} }    return fileArray;

Comment: Format that and put it in your question buddy :) That way everyone can see it properly.

Comment: What platform?  iOS? OSX? tvOS?

Comment: Not displaying images on image view?

Comment: @Sandy.M Just print your fileArray and check whether it has all the images.

Comment: Yes i m getting but image is not displaying on image view @AjithKumar

Comment: Can you please post fileArray's output here

Comment: Image Path--->=/Users/sandeepkumar/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/D4494CD4-8D2D-4A4C-97AE-F72B1A691BE2/data/Containers/Data/Application/328D9B3F-854D-49F5-AEAB-FCB4A519B038/Documents/Users/custinfo.pdf1.png @AjithKumar

Comment: @Sandy.M    Try this  NSData *imgData = [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:imageFilePath]];
    if (imgData != nil) {
        UIImage *thumbNail = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:imgData];
youImageView.image = thumbNail;
    }

Comment: when i m set image get nil value: myImageView.image = thumbNail;

Comment: please find the issue myImageView.image = thumbNil; when cursher hold on thumbNail i m getting image on but when i hold on myImageView its showing nil,and right showing Could not loadQuick Look Data for myImageView

Comment: try [myImageView setImage:thumbNail];

Comment: @AjithKumar nup its not getting on image view on view controller

Comment: @Sandy.M Just add background color to your imageview and Run and can you see the background color?

Comment: @AjithKumar when i mLoading in viewDidLoad there displaying but i m downloading from image B view controller to displaying in A viewController its not displaying on image view its showing on when cursher on image its image is there but its not be on image view?

Comment: @AjithKumar image link  imgView:
<UIImageView: 0x7ff47964f380; frame = (0 0; 612 792); opaque = NO; userInteractionEnabled = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0x7ff47b81f6d0>>

Comment: change your imageView.frame = CGRectMake(100,100,200,200);
Print image before assigning to imageView.

Comment: @AjithKumar after your given code i dint get any image but size in --mgView:
<UIImageView: 0x7fba88ce52d0; frame = (0 0; 680 1048); opaque = NO; userInteractionEnabled = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0x7fba88cbcdc0>>

Comment: @AjithKumar addsub view Could not load Quick Look data for “_drawingView”

Answer (score 2):

You should try this code to save and retrieve image from the document directory:

I have implemented these methods in AppDelegate.m

```
 -(NSString *)getDocumentDirectoryPath:(NSString *)Name
 {
      NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory,  NSUserDomainMask, YES);
      NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
      NSString *savedImagePath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:Name];
      NSLog(@"savedImagePath: %@", savedImagePath);
      return savedImagePath;
 }

 -(BOOL)saveImage:(UIImage *)image withName:(NSString *)Name
 {
      NSData *imageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(image);
      BOOL success = [imageData writeToFile:[AppDelegate getDocumentDirectoryPath:Name] atomically:NO];
      return success;
 }

 -(UIImage *)getRealtorImage:(NSString *)Name
 {    
      UIImage *img = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:[AppDelegate getDocumentDirectoryPath:Name]];
      return img;
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

@Sandy Please try the following code

```
    UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(100,100,200,200)];     
    NSData *imgData = [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:imageFilePath]];
        if (imgData != nil) 
        { 
             UIImage *thumbNail = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:imgData];
             imageView.image = thumbNail;                                                                                   
        }
[self.view addSubView:imageView];
```